# EJBCA reinstalation issue

Tags: mysql, jboss, mariadb, centos7, ejbca

my name is Adrian and I have a big problem.

I cannot reinstall EJBCA 6.3.1.1 with jboss 7.1 on centos7. After the  mariadb databases wipe, after the reinstalation and reconfiguration, I can only deploy ejbca with ant but I cannot install it with ant with error "ERROR: User 'tomcat' already exists in the database." in case I am giving there new name, and if I put there default name ManagementCA it show error message "ManahementCA already exists".

I was checking the database,there is no such user as tomcat, also I did not  find in any table in all databases CAs.

Can you please help resolving the issue?

Thank you.
Best regards,
Adrian Bardossy

Comment: The error speaks for itself. Clean the database before the reinstall

Comment: I did  it in mariadb database, I also checked the users, there is no user like this and also all tables in database are empty but I am still getting the same error, I don't know what to do, I was tryiing every possible way but no luck.

Comment: not only clean the tables, but also drop the whole database and recreate it. I believe you can't reinstall it on already 'used' database during the first install

Comment: mysqladmin -u root -p drop ejbca

Comment: found and resolved the issue, proiblem was it is using h2 database so i removed it from home and now everything is fine, thnaks for advices :)